# How to save canvas automatically?

Tags: javascript, canvas, save, fabricjs, auto

I am working on one project based on canvas. I am using fabric js version 1.7.22. 
Currently My all images and data are come from server through API calling.
But my some functionality make image in canvas which are not exist in server.

Now I am save that canvas into server through save button, at that time , I just upload that image on server.

and when card(design) is load again for edit , I just load that image and it can modified dynamically.

When user save card(design) again,
At that time I first check that if image loaded in re-edit state is modified. if yes then replace old image with new one and if No then just save other card(design) property into server.

Now come to main point.

As requirement of auto save functionality, I need to optimize my API calls and data that sent in request.

I send data into server through json. if only json is send in API then it's ok but when new modified image is uploaded, at that time API take more load.

Is there any tips , so that I am enable to upload my image when only update in canvas but not upload image when user go back in history of canvas (undo redo functionality) or not necessary to upload image.

I am in confusion , that how we can implement auto save functionality lightWeight and easy way.

Please help me if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using node with [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) on the server side, since fabricjs supports it (see [fabricjs on node](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4#node)). That way, you only have to upload the json and render the result on server side using fabricjs.